# "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" error when trying to replace src of an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe containing a chat of user1 and an A element that is meant to change the src of the iframe to user2's chat on click. The problem is that I get an "Unexpected token ILLEGAL" error everytime I run Replace(user). I'm using Chrome on a local server, by the way.

This is the HTML document. I've been trying out a variety of different ways to change the src (JS' native .setAttribute('src', url), using jQuery's .remove() and so on), but it kept telling me "Unexpected token ILLEGAL".

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
      function Replace(user){
        $("#chatframe").attr('src', "https://mystreamingwebsite.tv/chat/" + user);
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a onclick="Replace('user2');">Join RandomUsername's chat</a>
    <iframe id="chatframe" src="https://mystreamingwebsite.tv/chat/user1" border="none"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Can anyone help me please??? Thank you <3

Comment: Don't see id on `iframe` add `chatframe` as id

Answer (score -1, accepted):

escape double quotes:

```
<a onclick="javascript:Replace(\"user2\");">
```

Comment: Wow, thank you a lot! It really works. I don't know how this got a -1 vote.
I'm just a beginner with jQuery and the example code here really was just an example. The real code did have the chatframe id on the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

There are two proble with your given code. First your iframe does not have id attribute set to "chatframe".

I assume your code is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
      function Replace(user){
        $("#chatframe").attr('src', "https://mystreamingwebsite.tv/chat/" + user);
      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a onclick="Replace("user2");">Join RandomUsername's chat</a>
    <iframe id="chatframe" src="https://mystreamingwebsite.tv/chat/user1" border="none"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

So the problem here with line,

`<a onclick="Replace("user2");">Join RandomUsername's chat</a>`

here you have to use enclose user2 value in single quotes.

Answer is:

`<a onclick="Replace('user2');">Join RandomUsername's chat</a>`

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to add the id in the example and a.onclick actually has Replace('user2') in my version. Thank you for your gentle reminder, but I still get the same error. I just don't see why.